# .jar error - could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar

I tried to put HelloWorld in a .jar file and running it, but it doesn't work. I created the java file and typed in the program, and then wrote in cmd:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

and it worked. Then I entered

```
echo Main-Class: HelloWorld >manifest.txt
jar cvfm HelloWorld.jar manifest.txt HelloWorld.class
```

and got the output

```
added manifest
adding: HelloWorld.class(in = 426) (out= 288)(deflated 32%)
```

I then entered

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
HelloWorld.jar
```

and the first line worked, while the second line gave me an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class path\HelloWorld.jar
```

which is the same output I got (in a rapidly closing window) when I tried to open it with the java.exe file in 64 bit jre7\bin, jdk1.7.0_51\bin, jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin, as well as 32 bit jre7\bin. I've uninstalled and reinstalled both my jre and jdk and recreated my .class and .jar files, but the problem persists. I'm on win8.

Edit: I tried to do as aetheria suggested, but no luck. I put HelloWorld.java in path\com\stackoverflow\user\blrp, compiled it, and it worked by entering

```
java com.stackoverflow.user.blrp.HelloWorld
```

in path. I then created the manifest and jar by:

```
(echo Manifest-Version: 1.0
echo Class-Path: .
echo Main-Class: com.stackoverflow.user.blrp.HelloWorld) >manifest.txt
jar cvfm HelloWorld.jar manifest.txt com\stackoverflow\user\blrp\HelloWorld.class
```

and got the output

```
added manifest
adding: com/stackoverflow/user/blrp/HelloWorld.class(in = 454) (out= 312)(deflat
ed 31%)
```

but still, java -jar HelloWorld.jar worked and HelloWorld.jar didn't (same error). I also tried not doing the package thing, just the Class-Path in manifest, same result.

(Also, I solved the problem prior to asking the question by use of a .bat file, but it'd still be sweet to get that jar working.)

Comment: manifest should be packaged as /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF unzip any jar file to see example e.g jre/lib/rt.jar

Comment: print empty line to the end of manifest, it should work.

Comment: echo creates the empty line automatically (without the empty line, java -jar doesn't work either), and manifest is packaged correctly when the jar is created.

Comment: I did try your "echo" and it works for me with "java -jar HelloWorld.jar". You can tweak you windows registry to use same command to open jar wile, but normally windows use "javaw -jar HelloWorld.jar" command to open jar. javaw launcher is used for GUI applications without console.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks jbaliuka for the suggestion. I opened the registry editor (by typing regedit in cmd) and going to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > jarfile > shell > open > command, then opening (Default) and changing the value from

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*`

to

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*`

(I just removed the w in javaw.exe.) After that you have to right click a jar -> open with -> choose default program -> navigate to your java folder and open \jre7\bin\java.exe (or any other java.exe file in you java folder). If it doesn't work, try switching to javaw.exe, open a jar file with it, then switch back.

I don't know anything about editing the registry except that it's dangerous, so you might wanna back it up before doing this (in the top bar, File>Export).

Answer (score 10):

I found this question when I was looking for the answer to the above question.  But in my case the issue was the use of an 'en dash' rather than a 'dash'.  Check which dash you are using, it might be the wrong one.  I hope this answer speeds up someone else's search, a comment like this could have saved me a bit of time.

Comment: What are you using for an editor, Microsoft Word? Or you have a keyboard with special characters? I didn't downvote, but this seems like a problem few people will have since it would also crop up in any program that used dashes.

Comment: I should have been more clear, this was a clear result of a copy/paste problem.  The original command line had the en-dashes and I copied them into my own version.  Getting stuck until I passed the .JAR to 2 colleagues, one who ran it using my command line arguments, where it failed.  Then a 2nd who wrote his own command line arguments and and verified that it worked fine. This made me look at the command in ASCII code where i discovered the difference.  Thanks for the feed back.

Comment: I just found this answer after desperately searching and banging my head on my desk.  My problem is that the command line was cut and pasted out of Outlook.  One more thing to watch for...  Thanks @EuroTech

Comment: Wow, I forgot the dash. top cake.

Comment: I copied and pasted also, had a space before the dash and resulted in the same exact error. Copied and pasted into an arguments field in JMeter UI. Hard to see the space I guess.

Answer (score 8):

You can always run this:

```
java -cp HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld
```

`-cp HelloWorld.jar` adds the jar to the classpath, then `HelloWorld` runs the class you wrote.

To create a runnable jar with a main class with no package, add `Class-Path: .` to the manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: HelloWorld
```

I would advise using a `package` to give your class its own namespace. E.g.

```
package com.stackoverflow.user.blrp;

public class HelloWorld {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem couldn't find the answer so i went looking on other threads, I found that i was making my app with 1.8 but for some reason my jre was out dated even though i remember updating it. I downloaded the lastes jre 8 and the jar file runs perfectly. Hope this helps.