# Running JAR file could not find main class. Program will exit

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I've been looking around the google for this very common problem but found no answer. When i build and clean my project through NetBeans, I only have this content in my manifest.mf

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

I was expecting of something like what others have:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: dpsr.DPSR
```

..but I don't have it. I already have followed setting up my main class on the properties. and here's my main class by the way:

```
package dpsr;

import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class DPSR {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Nimbus isn't available");
        }
        new frmLogin().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

..when I run the command in the machine

> java -jar dpsr.jar

it only says

> Could not find the main class: ... Program will exit.

I do not want to continue my project unless I resolve this. I need this so that other computers can use my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.jar error - could not find or load main class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650851/jar-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions.

1. Right click on Project, select [Properties].
2. Select [Run] node on the left.
3. In the [Main Class] test field, use the <kbd>browse</kbd> button to select the main class you want as the launching class. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>
4. Clean an Build you project.
5. Open the files window and look in YourProject/dist/yourproject.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. You should see the **Main-Class** has been added/changed

Comment: ..hi, thank you for this reply..glad to have this..and i also found out that the jdk/jre of the pc where i want to run the program has lower version from the version i developed the program. :)