# .jar file error "could not find or load main class" with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar, intellij-14

This is my MainBot.java code:

```
public class MainBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainBot("my_private_token");
    }

    public MainBot(String token) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I have the following problem: When I try to execute the .jar file generated by IntelliJ, I get the following error:

```
could not find or load main class: MainBot
```

But when I look *in* the .jar file using WinRAR, I see this:

[image: jar file]

The *MainBot.class* file is there! The manifest file in the META-INF/ folder looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MainBot
```

And the the META-INF folder looks like this:

[image: meta-inf]

What did I do wrong? When exporting, I select the correct main file in *INTELLIJ*, add the META-INF directory to resources/ and then I build my artifact. How come that The MainBot file cannot be found, when it is there?! I also tried playing arond with the MAINFEST.MF file and tried changing the Main-Class to ../MainBot or something, but none of that worked.

EDIT: This is the artifact under Project Structure | Artifacts

[image]
[image]

Comment: May you share a sample project and artifact configuration under "Project structure | Artifacts"?

Comment: Given the presence of a module-info.class, you're using a modular project, then you shouldn't use the default package. Put `MainBot` in a package.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I did that, now is says that the main class cannot be found at `package.MainBot`.

Comment: Can you share MainBot code? Or at least class declaration and main method declaration?

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21650867/9391162

Comment: @msl I have added my MainBot declaration code.

Comment: @AMK that did sadly not work, as I have my MainBot.class in a package called entry.

Comment: It's in a package called entry? Not in the code examples and screenshots you have posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `META-INF` folder in your generated Jar has these 2 files -

```
SIGNINGGC.RSA
SIGNINGGC.SF
```

I assume that you are not signing the Jar. Then, these files must be coming from one of your dependancies when you are creating a Fat Jar. If any of your dependancies has a Signed Jar, then it could result into that `could not find or load main class:`  exception.

You can quickly find if this is the issue by removing those files with this command (referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37732156/11244881)) and try and run the code -

```
zip -d yourjar.jar 'META-INF/*.SF' 'META-INF/*.RSA' 'META-INF/*.DSA'
```

IntelliJ shows 2 Options while generating Jar. The first one will generate a Fat Jar. The other option will keep the other library jars intact and link with them using Manifest file.

Assuming all you need is to run your code, use the second option in the `Create Jar from Modules` Dialog box.

[image]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! Sadly, the zip command did not work, but manually deleting the files with WinRar did!

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to reproduce the error using a [sample application](https://github.com/devatherock/java-module-example) that uses gradle, following [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html), but I couldn't. The sample application has a module named `io.github.devatherock.example`, which holds the `module-info.java` file and a package named `io.github.devatherock.example`, which contains the main class `MainBot.java`. I have listed the main class as `io.github.devatherock.example.MainBot` in gradle which produces a jar file with below manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: io.github.devatherock.example.MainBot
```

The jar executes without any error. In the IDE, the structure of the source code looks like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Windows
after generating jar file, in generated folder run command

```
7z d yourjar.jar META-INF/*.SF META-INF/*.RSA META-INF/*.DSA -r
```

you must installed 7zip and added enviorment path